# How do you filter by image tags with the gcloud utility?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am using `gcloud` to list all the tags for an image. The image can have multiple tags so I am filtering with the following command.

```
gcloud container images list-tags us.gcr.io/myproj/myrepp/myimage --filter="tags[0]=abc"
```

This correctly returns a record, however, it only works if `abc` is the first tag for the image. How can I return a record if `abc` could be any of the tags, not just the first for the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your filter to be: `--filter="tags[]=abc"`

This allows for any tag that matches `abc`. Your command was limiting this to `tags[0]` (the first tag).

Comment: Thanks - gotta love how you can never find clear examples on google docs.  Only the spec/api  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list-tags